# Parse schema microdata and arrange them like Google data structure

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath, schema, microdata

Happy Thanksgiving day :)

I'm learning Javascript and Dom, and I would like to parse schemadata from HTML and arrage like Google data structure.

*Schema data information

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/Product">

  <div itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/Person">
  <span itemprop="birthday" datetime="2009-05-10">May 10th 2009</span>
  </div>

  <div itemprop="name"> Product name </div>
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Offer">
    <span itemprop="price" content="500.00"> USD 500 </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

*Google data structure
[image: Google data structure]

My questions are,

First, to parse top categories, "Product" and "Person", how can I select the node which contain attribute "[itemtype]" but "[itemprop]" using Javascript and DOM?

Second, due to the fact that Person node is childnode of Product, it is hard to exclude top category's childnode. If I select  category node, how can I exclude another category's childnode? In this case, I would like to exclude  category node while arranging  category.

I found this code snippet from searching, however, this does not work what I want to like Google.

```
var result = {};
var items = [];
document.querySelectorAll("[itemscope]")
  .forEach(function(el, i) {
    var item = {
      "type": [el.getAttribute("itemtype")],
      "properties": {}
    };
    var props = el.querySelectorAll("[itemprop]");
    props.forEach(function(prop) {
      item.properties[prop.getAttribute("itemprop")] = [
        prop.content || prop.textContent || prop.src
      ];
      if (prop.matches("[itemscope]") && prop.matches("[itemprop]")) {
        var _item = {
          "type": [prop.getAttribute("itemtype")],
          "properties": {}
        };
        prop.querySelectorAll("[itemprop]")
          .forEach(function(_prop) {
            _item.properties[_prop.getAttribute("itemprop")] = [
              _prop.content || _prop.textContent || _prop.src
            ];
          });
        item.properties[prop.getAttribute("itemprop")] = [_item];
      }
    });
    items.push(item)
  })

result.items = items;

console.log(result);

document.body
  .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2) + "<pre>");

var props = ["Blendmagic", "ratingValue"];

// get the 'content' corresponding to itemprop 'ratingValue' 
// for item prop-name 'Blendmagic'
var data = result.items.map(function(value, key) {
  if (value.properties.name && value.properties.name[0] === props[0]) {
    var prop = value.properties.reviews[0].properties;
    var res = {},
      _props = {};
    _props[props[1]] = prop[props[1]];
    res[props[0]] = _props
    return res
  };
})[0];

console.log(data);
document.querySelector("pre").insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2) + "<pre>");
```

Should I use XPATH instead of DOM?

Many thanks to you all :)

Comment: if you have the source data, this is much easier to do using handlebars/mustache

Answer (score 0):

I've just implemented a solution that mostly works.

One issue with selectors is that I could not work out how to only get next level attributes. e.g. at the start you only want top level itemscopes, then you want the itemprops directly inside each etc.

I eventually parsed the DOM manually. i.e. element by element, looping through the children recursively.

As I go I keep track of the context in relation to the current object being processed. I add properties to it as I find them.

If I hit another itemscope then I create a new inner object and parse that scope using that object.

Then I worked out how to do itemid and itemref!

Comment: Hi Tony. I solved this issue using XPATH. I couldn’t find the better solution than XPATH.